# How can one find all the contracts invoiced against a given purchase order in Upwork Enterprise?

Tags: upwork

I'm using several purchase orders with Upwork Enterprise. I have invoiced several contracts against each of these purchase orders. How can I find all the contracts invoiced against a given purchase order in Upwork Enterprise?

I tried going to https://www.upwork.com/nx/reports/client/purchase-orders/: it gives the list of purchase orders as as well as the number of contracts for each purchase order, but it doesn't seem possible to list all the contracts invoiced against a given purchase order on that page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can go to https://www.upwork.com/nx/reports/client/contracts-audit/ -> export. It'll download a CSV file. Each row contains one contract. The columns include the purchase order as well as the contract information. Here are all the The columns:

- Contract Title
- Team Name
- Contract Type
- Contract Status
- Contract Rate
- Weekly Limit
- Remaining Milestones
- Contact Person
- Staffed by
- Talent name
- PO number
- PO description
- Spend
- Fees
- On Behalf Of
- On Behalf Of (email)